# Is there a modified UML version for Android Applications?

Tags: java, android, android-activity, uml

I'm rather new to android development but have a decent knowledge of C++/UML diagrams. Is there any way sort of UML that incorporates both layouts as well as Java classes in a diagram to structure your program? I'm not sure if I'm crazy for asking this or if I should just stick to using UML to model my classes but I thought this would be very helpful to have a sort of system to 'quickly' be able to visualize an android application including layouts and java classes. Any feedback is appreciated!

Comment: UML is pretty much dead.  There was some hype about it 15 years ago, but I've never seen it in any professional setting.  The replacement tends to be just less formal class diagrams for documentation, with the idea of generating code from models thrown out as it never worked very well and tended only to automate the easy parts anyway.  By the way, this comes from someone who spent most of his career working in a mix of C++ and Java, not a pure Java background.  Even in C++ it isn't really used.

Comment: The [Interaction Flow Modeling Language](http://programmers.stackexchange.com/a/271054/129832) designed by Object Management Group (the same group behind UML and FUML and BPMN) maybe the way to combine layouts and classes together you are looking for

Comment: @GabeSechan using C++ as an example of good engineering tool/practices/whatever was a hype about 25 years ago. I've never seen it to be used in a well designed product which made it on time with good documentation necessary for future maintenance written. I've seen it to be used in a few nightmare expensive but super proud projects where developers celebrated their ability to compile the product at the end of the sprint

Comment: @xmojmr C++ was mentioned to show I use the same technology set as the original asker.  But sorry to inform you, but UML is absolutely not used anywhere in industry anymore.  It was barely used when it was hot.  There were more projects using C++ started yesterday than used UML in the last year.

Comment: @GabeSechan perhaps we both live in different subspaces of the industry. I agree that the fact that I don't see something in your bubble of the universe does not mean it does not exist and vice versa. Can you backup your claims about "UML is dead", "anywhere in industry", "number of C++ projects started yesterday", "number of projects that used UML in the last year" by some believable facts, statistics etc.? Your/mine personal experience is certainly insufficient to draw some conclusion out of this discussion branch which would be useful for OP's problem

Comment: The fact that this is the first time I've seen the term UML in 5 or 6 years is a good first sign.  I'm not really bubbled-  I've worked for startups and Fortune 100s, everything from firmware to mobile apps to back end webservices.  Never seen UML used.  Never in all of that time even heard of UML actually being used.  Also there's the fact that searching for "UML popularity" in google has no relevant results on the first page newer than 2012.  Or that "UML opinions" has no positive results first page other than tool vendors.  Its so dead I can't even find stats on it.

Comment: Heck, "UML usage statistics" doesn't even have a result post 2007 on the first page.  If anyone was actually using tool vendors would still be touting those stats as why you need their software.  That's gopher levels of dead.

Comment: @GabeSechan The main issue of UML was the complexity and heaviness of tools. FYI GenMyModel the online agile modeling tools gets hundreds of new users each day, mostly for UML.

Comment: @Xaelis The main problem of UML wasn't tools, it was that XML was an overly complex way of doing things that tried to solve a problem that didn't exist.  People had needs of drawing simple diagrams like class hierarchies and state machines.  They didn't need an entirely new language with hundreds of rules that combined dozens of unconnected diagram types.  The step from "here's a simple tool to draw diagrams" to "here's a complex visual language to do 3 dozen things" is what killed it.  You still have people drawing simple diagrams, they just don't use UML to do it.

Comment: @GabeSechan I agree too complexity is bad for modeling, but drawing tool is a bad solution. It is like using a vocabulary without any grammar rules. It is much more difficult to use and to be understand. It is definitely a tool issue to have real modeling tool with the agility of a drawing tool.

Comment: @GabeSechan Google page-rank for sociological queries (though related) is irrelevant argument. In 2014 Stack Overflow received [~1000 UML questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/272228/how-many-uml-related-questions-were-posted-since-ever-per-year). Yes, [there are sceptics](http://www.drdobbs.com/architecture-and-design/uml-25-do-you-even-care/240163702), but when I'm in design-doubts I do some UML modeling. An alternative is to produce hard-to-maintain agile mess and quickly move on...

Comment: @GabeSechan ...My experience: about ~25% projects I worked on used some UML (and only 1 is visible to Google) and >80% of business analysts and software architects were not able to produce comprehensive requirement specification or architecture design documents before/during/after at all (the less in an _industry standard_ form like `BPMN` or `UML`). My conclusion is not it's dead because the responsible people are not capable to use it. Your bubble is different

Comment: I'd say class diagram is a little to broad to consider all of them UML-  the idea predates UML by 10 years at least.  UML alone had 800.  But 800 is really nothing- Lisp had 600+ and is completely dead outside of academia.  DOS has 250.  Another way to look at it-  the UML tag has 
19 asked this week, 60 this month.  That's similar to WEKA, the number of questions asked on navigation-drawer, and less than ASP.NET HtmlHelper class.  Its in page 50 when sorting by most popular tags.  In fact DOS is catching up on it, with 7 asked this week and 20 this month.  That's not a thriving technology.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can visualize any type of application on any type of environment using standard UML withou modifications. 
But, UML allows to create profiles, to build user's specific set of element to simplify of specific domain model. (it is extension mechanism of UML) For example html, SOAP, GUI etc.

For more details read UML Superstructure document, section profiles.